# Rijndael-256 Encryption Decryption in PHP

Tags: php, drupal, mcrypt, rijndael, rijndaelmanaged

I have a situation where I have to encrypt and decrypt SOAP xml in PHP. I am trying to encrypt the Envelope of a soap xml. Encryption is working, but decryption is not. For encryption and decryption I use the code specified in this article:

http://blog.djekldevelopments.co.uk/?p=334

If the input string contains any special characters(eg:'<>'), then decryption is not working. How can I solve this?

```
function decrypt($string = "")
  {
$keyfile = "./AES.keyz";
$keyfile = file($keyfile);
    $key = base64_decode($keyfile[0]);
    $iv = base64_decode($keyfile[1]);
$string = base64_decode($string);
return strippadding(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $string,MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
   }
```

Comment: @Alix Axel..isue when decrypting special charactersusing mcrypt

Answer (score 0):

MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 ia not AES with 256 bit key , its RIJNDAEL with a 256 bit block size.

To decrypt  256 bit AES , you need to use MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 with a 256 bit key.